# Primefaces InputGroup not working

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 6.1 with premium theme(avalon).
I have a problem in using **InputGroup** feature. 
[Primefaces InputGroup](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputGroup.xhtml)
The grouping was not happening.
When I check into this issue, I found that the style classes **ui-inputgroup** and **ui-inputgroup-addon** are not available in any of the css files shipped with primefaces/theme bundle.

I think, adding default bootstrap files may fix this issue. But, As Primefaces itself is providing most of the bootstrap features by default, I will go for that as my last option only if there is no other solution.

I have added primefaces.jar file and avalon themes resources to the project.

So, my question is, Is there any resource which I missed to add?
or Is the way I implemented is wrong?

```
<div class="ui-inputgroup">
        <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">Find</span>
        <p:autoComplete styleClass="form-control" id="search-item" value="#{searchBean.searchItem}"
            label="#{searchBean.searchItem}" completeMethod="#{searchBean.autoCompleteItem}"
            var="item" itemLabel="#{item}" itemValue="#{item}" forceSelection="true">
        </p:autoComplete>
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have this problem too .

Answer (score 3):

Input group is available from version 6.1.4 [primefaces changelog](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+label%3A6.1.4) So any version after this will work

Comment: That's an absurd for "showcase" then... Why they is being showing what is not "Community" yet?